# What's the difference between multi-(single outputs) NN vs single-(multi targets) NN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm working on this following autoregressive problem with Keras/TF :

Inputs :

***m*** examples x **10** timesteps (sequence length) x **7** features

(With each value being a real value)

Outputs :

***m*** examples x **4** targets/"labels" (real values that I want to predict)

So far, using LSTMs **with Dense layers at the end (edited)**. So for one example, I give 7 features in a sequence of size 10 and I just want 4 real values out of it (I'm predicting current values according to previous values).

## **My question is the following**  :

What is the difference between predicting :

a. 1 output with dimensions **m** x **4**

b. 4 outputs with each of dimensions **m** x **1**

I've tried both methods and I don't see any particular difference but I want to understand what they both do. In the second case, I know I can specify different losses and different weight for the losses on each variable that I want to predict but this seems to be less correct than the first method.

```py
#python / Keras-TF
#a. multi output
model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = [Output1,Output2,Output3,Output4])
prediction = model.predict(X_test_normalized) #returns an inconvenient list of 4 [2 by 1 vectors] which in the end gives me m*4 real values as wanted

###### vs ######

#b. single output
model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = [Output1]) #vector of dimension 4
prediction = model.predict(X_test_normalized) #returns a m*4 matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not make a difference most of the time. If your output layers are dense ones, each of them will have a n*1 weight matrix. If you have a single output layer the weight has the shape n*4 instead. Generally one big output layer is faster, as one big matrix multiplication often faster than multiple small ones.

You can weight the outputs of the single output layer, too. Just multiply it with a weight vector of the size of your outputs before giving it to the loss.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'm interested in the "most of the time" part, what do you mean?

Comment: Most of the time means: for the most common layers like convolution or dense. I just didn't want to say that there is or never will be a type of layer where this is not true. For the time being, most of the time is all the time.